# Can you always apply the log transform over a positive inequality constraint?

Tags: metric-spaces, convex-optimization, mahalanobis-distance

I'm having trouble understanding when can you take the log of a constraint in a general way (is this something you can always do for positive inequalities $\geq 1$, or there are limitations?)...it's something that was done in this article: [https://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/nips02-metric.pdf](https://ai.stanford.edu/%7Eang/papers/nips02-metric.pdf). I will state the problem nonetheless:

Suppose we define the Mahalanobis distance, with $A$ being a positive definite matrix.:
$$
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\begin{align}
 d(x, y) = d_A(x, y) = \norm{x-y}_A = \sqrt{(x-y)^TA(x-y)}
\end{align}
$$

And then a set of pairs of points we say are *"similar"*:
$$
\begin{align}
 & \mathcal{S}: (x_i, x_j) \in \mathcal{S} \quad \text{if $x_i$ and $x_j$ are similar} \\
    & \mathcal{D}: (x_i, x_j) \notin \mathcal{S}
\end{align}
$$

We want to learn an $A$ such that items deemed "similar" have a small distance. To avoid the trivial solution $A=0$ we include a constraint that "dissimilar" items MUST have a distance greater than 1. So an optimization problem can be defined:

$$
\begin{align}
\min_{A} & \sum_{(x_i, x_j) \in \mathcal{S}} \norm{x_i-x_j}^2_A \\
 \text{s.t.} & \sum_{(x_i, x_j) \in \mathcal{D}} \norm{x_i-x_j}_A \geq 1 \\
 & A \succeq 0
\end{align}
$$

In the article, for the case of a diagonal $A$, they wrote a function which is equivalent to the optimization problem from above.
$$
\begin{align}
 g(A)=g(A_{11},...,A_{nn}) = \sum_{(x_i, x_j)\in \mathcal{S}} \norm{x_i-x_j}^2_A - \log \left(\sum_{(x_i, x_j)\in \mathcal{D}} \norm{x_i-x_j}_A \right)
\end{align}
$$

My question...Why $log$? When using Lagrange multipliers, that should have been written as $\sum_{(x_i, x_j)\in \mathcal{S}} \norm{x_i-x_j}^2_A-\lambda (\sum_{(x_i, x_j) \in \mathcal{D}} \norm{x_i-x_j}_A - 1 - s^2) $ (here $s$ is a slack variable). Can you take the $log$ anytime the constraint inequality is positive definite? Also, could you please share some books where this is treated in a general way?

Comment: You don't need to add a slack variable to the Lagrangian (at optimality, either $\lambda$ or $s$ is $0$)

Comment: You can replace $\sum_{(x_i, x_j) \in \mathcal{D}} \norm{x_i-x_j}_A \geq 1$ with $\log(\sum_{(x_i, x_j) \in \mathcal{D}} \norm{x_i-x_j}_A) \geq \log(1)$. Adding the constraint to the objective is almost the same as $g$ except for a missing Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: Thank you for both comments. So in general, any monotonic function could be applied over the constraints as the objective won't change? What about the rate of convergence then?

Comment: The rate of convergence depends on the algorithm. I think it is more interesting to look at convergence. WIthout the log transformation, the constraint is not convex, while convexity is a requirement for many algorithms. Is the constraint convex after the transformation?